# How to concatenate more sparse matrices into one in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a problem in python where i would like to merge some sparse matrices into one. The sparse matrices are of csr_matrix type and have same amount of rows. When I use hstack to stack them together I obtain an array of matrices, but I would like to obtain a single matrix with the number of rows (which is the same for every matrix) and as the number of columns the sum of the columns number of every matrix.
Thanks for support.

Comment: `sparse.hstack` is the tool to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`scipy.sparse.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html). For example:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

x = sparse.csr_matrix(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 10)))
y = sparse.csr_matrix(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 10)))
xy = sparse.hstack([x, y])

print(xy.shape)
# (10, 20)

print(type(xy))
# <class 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'>
```

Comment: This solved the problem, I was using the hstack method from numpy instead of the one from scipy.sparse. Thanks!

Comment: Question for those familiar with the code, which I haven't looked at - does this concatenate in-place? We've got some home-grown code for doing in-place concatenation of sparse matrices because the author reported that the scipy/numpy methods for this used too much memory, and I haven't had time to dig into the source code to see how much is too much.